# XSLT-Create elements dynamically with java

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I have a method that should create and then append a xsl:template tag into the xml file given below.

Java:

```
...
tF = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilderFactory fact = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
fact.setNamespaceAware(true);
DocumentBuilder builder2 = fact.newDocumentBuilder();
id = builder2.parse(ctx.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/identity.xsl"));
...
attributes_only(id);

StreamSource xmlSource = new StreamSource(ctx.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/input.xml"));
response.setContentType("text/html");

DOMSource ds_id = new DOMSource(id);
Transformer mine = tF.newTransformer(ds_id);
DOMResult output = new DOMResult();
mine.transform(xmlSource, output);
...
private void attributes_only(Document d) {
    Element root = d.getDocumentElement();

    Element e = d.createElement("xsl:template");
    e.setAttribute("match","a|b|c");
    root.appendChild(e);
}
...
```

XML:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
   <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!--    This is what I want to achieve
<xsl:template match="a|b|c">
</xsl:template>
--> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am using org.w3c.dom and everything runs fine except for this method. The error message (from tomcat) is something like "xsl:template is not allowed in this position in the stylesheet" and an empty xml is produced. Does anyone have an idea about what's wrong?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why on earth are you transforming a stylesheet using Java and DOM, rather than using XSLT itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create elements and attributes in a namespace-aware DOM tree you need to use the DOM level 2 `*NS` versions of the methods, rather than the (ancient) DOM level 1 methods that pre-date namespaces.

```
Element e = d.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform", "xsl:template");
e.setAttributeNS(null, "match","a|b|c");
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try setting the Namespace of the template-element with setPrefix, createElementNS or the like. When you add the element via dom it might not know about the Namespace you mean by the prefix.